# Thermistor calculations using B-Parameter equation

Tags: thermistor

I have a USUR1000-104G as seen [here](http://www.ussensor.com/sites/default/files/downloads/USUR1000.pdf).

From what I understand by these links [here](http://www.ussensor.com/usur1000) and [here](http://www.ussensor.com/thermistor-part-number-usur1000-104g-resistance-vs-temperature-table)

and using the b-parameter equation from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor).

I have the following values:

\$ \beta = 3890 \$

\$ \dfrac{R}{R_0} = 1 \$

This is where I get confused in converting this to a temperature.

I am not sure I follow the equation on how they solve for R in the wikipedia page under the B-parameter section.

For instance; how do I get T in:

\$ e ^ {{\beta}/{T}} \$

for \$ R = r_{\infty} \cdot e ^ {{\beta}/{T}} \$?

Sorry for the vague question; I guess I am just not fully understanding the equation and a little bit of a more detailed explanation may clear things up for me.

**EDIT:**

As a follow-up I have a thermistor wired to a 3.3volt 100k ohm resistor using the following schematic: [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/570).

The voltages read from 0-1 as a floating point into my code and I have the following code in concordance to the formula discussed earlier in the problem.

```
 final float reading = input_.read();
 double temperature = 3890/(Math.log((reading*100000)/0.215628)) - 298.5;
```

However; when I display that code I get a celsius reading of 0 degrees celsius as my room temperature reading.
Which is obviously incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T in the equation you reference is just the temperature that the thermistor is at.

The assumption here is that you want to find the resistance R of the thermistor as a function of the temperature T.

If you want to find T as a function of R, then you need the inverse of that function.

Try an example:

Say the thermistor measures 50.0K ohms, the temperature T can be found:

\$R_0\$ = 100,000

B = 3890

\$T_0\$ = 25°C = 298.15K

\$r_\infty\$ = \$R_0e^{-\frac{B}{T_0}}\$ = 0.215628

T = \$ \frac {B}{ln(\frac {R} {r_\infty} )}\$ = 314.88 K or 41.73°C

You can see that this agrees with the value shown in the table you linked:

[image]

Comment: Thanks the expansion of the problem really helped me out.

Comment: If you have time Spehro, I'd like you to check out my followup question with an algorithm I implemented using Java Code.

Comment: Subtract 273.15 rather than 298.5 and I think you'll get a better number.